# Как сделать динамический вывод текста в kivy, наподобие терминала

Tags: python, вывод, kivy

Доброго времени всем. Вопрос такой. Как можно реализовать динамический вывод в kivy.

То есть к примеру есть нечто такое:

```
 for i in xrange(10):
     print('Print-' + i)
```

Результат хотелось бы получить такой же, какой будет и в простой консоли.

```
Print-1
Print-2
Print-3
```

и т. д

Answer (score 0):

А в чём, собственно, проблема?
Вывод такой и будет, только надо i преобразовать в строку:

```
print('Print-'+str(i))
```

или воспользоваться подстановкой:

```
print('Print-%s'%i)
```